# h:selectOneMenu in p:dataTable doesn't submit its value

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I have a question about selectOneMenu and settting the values.  I have an Object SampleDesc that has and ID, Text, and a `List<SampleDescValues>`.  For each datatable row the Text is the output label and the select one menu values are the `List<SampleDescValues>`.
XHTML:

```
    <h:panelGroup id="tables">
    <p:dataTable resizableColumns="true" 
             var="sampleDesc" id="SampleDescTable" rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                     value="#{sampleBean.sampleDescList.list}" 
                     rendered="#{sampleBean.sampleDescList.list.size() gt 0}">
            <p:column>
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{sampleDesc.sampleDescText}"/>
                </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:selectOneMenu required="#{sampleBean.sampleDescList.list.size() gt 0}" converter="#{sampleDescValueConverter}" 
                                                         id="SampleDescValue" value="#{sampleBean.selectedSampleDescList.get(rowIndex)}">                                                         
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{sampleDesc.sampleDescValues}" var="sdv" 
                                       itemLabel="#{sdv.sampleDescValuesText}" itemValue="#{sdv}" />

                        </h:selectOneMenu>
                </p:column>    
        </p:dataTable>
</h:panelGroup>
```

I have the converter setup and it works because ive set it to a single SampleDescValue and it set the value.

The problem is when i try and populate the form with a Sample from the database it can only set one of the dropdowns when there could be an infinite number of selectonemenu's

I set the value selected to `private List<SampleDescValue> selectedSampleDescList;`

When i try and submit it does nothing, it works when the datatable is not rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your menu value is wrong:

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{sampleBean.selectedSampleDescList.get(rowIndex)}">
```

It's not possible to perform a `set` operation on this EL expression.

Use the brace notation instead:

```html
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{sampleBean.selectedSampleDescList[rowIndex]}">
```

Note that this expects a non-null `selectedSampleDescList`. So make sure that you've already properly initialized it with a `new ArrayList<>()` beforehand. EL won't do that for you. It will only set the list items using `List#add(index, object)` method.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, this expression

```
#{sampleBean.sampleDescList.list.size() gt 0}
```

can be simplified as follows

```
#{not empty sampleBean.sampleDescList.list}
```

And this is unnecessary in the `required` attribute of the `<h:selectOneMenu>` as it would *always* evaluate `true` at that point. Just use `required="true"` directly instead.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what i was looking for.  I have a related question on how to access 'private List<List<SampleDescValues>> selectedSampleDescList' object from EL Expression.  I have a nested datatable that generates dropdowns the same way as this example so i need to keep track of them somehow.  sampleBean.selectedSampleDescList[rowIndex][subDataTableRowIndex] didnt work.

Comment: Did you preinitialize every nested item with a new `ArrayList`?

Comment: i figured it out i wasnt making a new arraylist for each sublist.  Thanks again!